# Bernoulli's equation and reference frames

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, flow, bernoulli-equation

So I was thinking about this while driving home the other day.

I've never been quite clear on why when you drive with the windows down air rushes into your car. I thought this might be explained by Bernoulli's equation for incompressible flow, but I ran into what seems to be a contradiction. If we consider the problem from the reference of the car, the air in the car is stationary and the air outside the car has a certain velocity. Then, Bernoulli's equation implies the pressure outside the car is lower than that inside the car. However, if we take the reference frame of the road, the air in the car is moving and then the pressure in  side the car is lower. Intuitively, this second situation seems to be correct since air apparently flows into the car (from high pressure to low pressure). However there seems to be a contradiction, as the pressure gradient depends on reference frame. So my question is what has gone wrong here? Is this a situation in which bernoulli's principle simply isn't applicable? Did I make some sort of mistake in my application of the principle?

Comment: If it were a flow from one pressure regime to another, it would only last a very short time, since the car's volume is enclosed. After that, you get flow out equals flow in. So if you feel air blowing into the car, you can be sure it is also blowing out, but since your hand is inside the car, you feel the inflow. You don't feel the outflow. (Give poor Bernoulli a rest :)

Comment: Nevertheless, the conceptual question regarding reference frames and Bernoulli's principle is a good one, even if it doesn't apply so much to the car window question

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey; Ok the part about the air blowing in being the same as the air blowing makes sense, otherwise my car would implode/explode. But maybe this is a better question: If I'm driving with the windows closed and can instantly open them (maybe by smashing them or something), which way will the air flow initially?

Comment: [The Bernoulli equation is frame-dependent](http://iopscience.iop.org/0143-0807/32/2/022/). PDF [here](http://www.loreto.unican.es/Carpeta2012/EJP(Mungan)Bernoulli(2011).pdf). The pressure drop depends on the frame of reference.

Comment: @VijayMurthy; yes that seems to answer my question. thank you.

Comment: @PatEugene: In that case, there should be an initial, short-time, outflow, until the pressure inside equals the lower pressure due to air velocity outside. Assuming the car is airtight. (Supposedly the old VWs could float :)

Comment: @VijayMurthy If we talk about it in the Special Theory of Relativity, is it also frame-dependent?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/bernoulli.pdf). Bernoulli's equation is frame-dependent.

Comment: @VijayMurthy Thank you, it is quite an amazing result.

Comment: @VijayMurthy it would be great if you make an answer based on your comments

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bernoulli's equation is frame-dependent as the following paper shows it in a nice way

[The Bernoulli equation in a moving reference frame](http://iopscience.iop.org/0143-0807/32/2/022/)

The essence of the argument is to realize that in a frame where the obstacles, around which the fluid moves, are not stationary, these surfaces do non-zero work. And one must account for this work done when using the Bernoulli equation.

A better way is to look at the generalized Bernoulli equation as done [here](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.15812), which also covers viscous fluids.

Comment: Bernoulli equation is related to energy conservation. One must be careful when using the law of conservation of energy in a moving frame. Constraint forces can do non-zero work, and this must be accounted for. The correct way is to directly look at equations motion or to use the work-energy theorem, which is frame-independent. A nice situation that exemplifies this idea is [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/is-the-energy-conserved-in-a-moving-frame-of-reference)

Comment: Hi, this second link and third link have rotted.

Comment: Can you kindly add free resources links. At least provide the main equation "The Bernoulli equation in a moving reference frame" in your answer.