# Bernoulli principle and relativity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, bernoulli-equation

Bernoulli principle has many applications like airplanes take off etc. But when we apply Bernoulli's principle we dont refer the reference frame in which we measure the velocity of air for example. Same happens with magnus effect. Does Bernoulli's principle (equation) apply for all reference frames?

Comment: Interesting article: short answer is "no" http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/bernoulli.pdf

Comment: thanks but then how we know when to apply the bernoullis principle ?

Comment: The principle is frame-dependent, so it's only applicable in certain frames of reference relative to a moving fluid: i.e. inertial frames.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44101/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bernoulli's equation and reference frames](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44101/)